# Magento2 Hide/Show custom product types in catalog and search based on condition

Tags: magento2, module, custom-product-type

I've setup a custom product type and now I want to filter them out of the catalog and search without changing the visibility attribute.

Then I want to show them selectively base on a specified condition (ie. if that product is associated with the specific customer ID, but the logic for this part is already in place).

I am trying to reverse engineer the code to find where the catalog module generates the query to get the product list and intercept it with a plugin or override the class entirely. I feel that I am close but I can't quite find the exact point.

Does anyone know how can I approach this?

Thank you!

Comment: Which is your Magento version?

Comment: Magento CE 2.1.3